# Solidity Test - which are the variables and keywords over here

Tags: solidity, truffle

Can anyone help me in understanding what is happening over here? I understand that the contract name is *TestAdoption*, but after that - what is the first word "Adoption"? The second word "adoption".  I do acknowledge and note that my contract has been defined as "Adoption" - so the first word should be that contract. But then what is the variable being equated (set) to?

```
contract TestAdoption {
  Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());
  }
```

Here is the link, which I have been studying: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop

Comment: `Adoption` is the type of the variable. `adoption` is the variable. `Adoption(...)` casts the value to the type `Adoption`. `DeployedAddresses.Adoption()` is presumably a Truffle thing... that must return the address of the deployed contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());
```

The first keyword, `Adoption`, is just declaring the type of the variable (which in this case is an instance the "Adoption" contact which has been defined elsewhere).

The second, `adoption`, is just naming that variable. You could call it anything.

Then the function `Adoption( someAddress )` is saying "retrieve the deployed instance of the `Adoption`contract at `someAddress`.

I'm not sure precisely what this does, `DeployedAddresses.Adoption()`, because you haven't defined DeployedAddresses anywhere in your question. But whatever it is, it will be returning the address of the deployed `Adoption` contract, because the `Adoption()` function takes an address as the argument.